# Ordering posts by date using Flask

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm attempting to order a list of blog posts in ascending and descending order by their date.

```
from sqlalchemy import desc
@app.route('/')
@app.route('/home')
def home():
    posts = Post.query.order_by(desc(post.date)).limit(3).all()
    return render_template('home.html', title='Home', posts=posts)
```

I keep getting: 'function' object has no attribute 'date'

The db is set to hold a date, so where am I going wrong? I assume that asc will work if I replace the desc in this example.

Thanks

Comment: Please replace desc(post.date) with desc(Post.date).

Comment: @DivakarPatil That's exactly it, thank you, I can't seem to say you answered that but thank you

Answer (score 0):

Replace the "p" in `post.date` to capital "P". as `Post.date`.
Thank you.